# Correct Laravel Join with Date fix

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've two data tables One is vehicles and other is bookings. I select vehicles from vehicles table to booking when I book them. Now I want to check the status of booked and available vehicles but I am getting vehicles when that are booked on available status.original booking form is as under. I am updating the solved code.

$date = '2018-11-14';

```
  $data = DB::table('vehicles')
     ->select('bookings.*', 'vehicles.*')
     ->Join('bookings', function($query) use ($date) {
          $query
              ->on ('bookings.vehicle_id', '!=', 'vehicles.id')
              ->where('eventDate', '=', $date);
      })
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split queries.

Booked:

```
$booked = DB::table('vehicles')
   ->select('bookings.*', 'vehicles.*')
   ->join('bookings', function($query) use ($date) {
        $query
            ->on('bookings.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
            ->where('date', '=', $date);
    })
    ->get();
```

Available:

```
$available = DB::table('vehicles')
    ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($date) {
       $query
           ->select(DB::raw(1))
           ->from('bookings')
           ->whereRaw('bookings.vehicle_id = vehicle.id')
           ->where('bookings.event_date','=', $date);
    })
    ->get();
```

Change return:

```
return view('bookings.status', compact('available', 'booked'));
```

And use $available and $booked instead of one data variable in your view.

**OR**

Get all data in one query.

```
$data = DB::table('vehicles')
->select('bookings.*', 'vehicles.*')
->leftJoin('bookings', function($query) use ($data) {
    $query
        ->on('bookings.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
        ->where('date', '=', $date);
})
->get();
```

And check for example for empty 'event_date' in view.

Available:

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    @if(!$row->event_date)
        ...table row...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Booked:

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    @if($row->event_date)
        ...table row...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: But I am not getting the data of bookings table on the booked dates

Comment: Ok, looks like I didn't understand task. You need all vehicles (booked and not booked) with data from bookings table (if booked)?

Comment: Yes. I need data from both tables. You got it

Comment: I've tried both codes. On the first one you edited. The bookings are showing perfectly. Booked data shows on booking dates and when there no bookings the are no data. But vehicles are not changing, Vehicles are showing the remain. they show available while on they are booked on those dates

Comment: Ok, can you extend your question and add your tables schemes and example scheme of result you want to recieve.

Comment: Ok I am posting the whole migrations

Comment: I have added the migration files .

Comment: I have added original migrations and pictures of UI as well.

Comment: You are such a life saver. Ia m running the code and it is working perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

used right join

```
$date = '2018-11-12';

  $data =DB::table('bookings')
              ->rightJoin('vehicles','vehicles.id','!=', 'bookings.vehicle_id')
              ->select('bookings.*', 'vehicles.*')
              ->where('bookings.event_date',$date)  //for date used where
              ->orWhereNull('bookings.event_date')   //if your bookings table is empty then add orWhereNull condition to get all rows...
              ->get();
```

Comment: Date is condition if we ignore that the purpose of query will be useless.

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I ll feed back you after running the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$data =DB::table('vehicles')
              ->join('bookings','bookings.vehicle_id', '!=', 'vehicles.id')
              ->select('bookings.*', 'vehicles.*')
              ->whereDate('bookings.event_date','=', $date)
              ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bookings.event_date' in 'where clause